# Why are feeds not up to date?

Tags: feed, discussion

Why are there differences between the newest questions displayed on Stack Overflow, and the feed generated for same resource?

Say, if I want to check the newest questions published under any category, via feed, I get the latest question atleat 3 minutes and sometimes 20 minutes later than it appears on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Resources would be my guess. It costs less to cache it longer. Feeds aren't as crucial as the questions-page itself.

Comment: This has kind of erked me too, it relegates my google-reader into displaying recently answered questions, rather than asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this applies to feeds in general - they are not always immediately updated. Or rather, the updates are not always immediately visible. I've been to new posts/articles before they appeared in my feed reader.

Given the volume of activity on SO, I'm not surprised that the feed is not always up to date.